# Флаги, конфиги и переменные окружения

Tags: переменные, config, переменные-среды

В каких случаях лучше использовать [переменные окружения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B) для задания параметров утилиты, сервиса (ПО). Когда -- конфиги, а когда -- флаги. На мой взгляд использование только лишь переменных окружения ничем не хуже использования конфигов и переменных окружения с примесью флагов.

Данный вопрос не может иметь одного конкретного ответа и имеет множество ответов в зависимости от ситуации. Пожалуйста, расскажите Ваше мнение о данной проблеме.

Comment: Что такое "флаги"? Под конфигами подразумеваются файлы с конфигами? Параметры прокинутые через консоль - это считается переменными окружения?

Comment: Флаги -- аргументы, с которыми запускается тулза. Да, файлы с конфигами

Comment: Переменные окружения -- это переменные окружения (добавил ссыль). Например `PATH` в ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменные окружения:

1. Доступны отовсюду.
2. Удобно, если разным программам нужны одни и те же переменные (к примеру, путь до исполняемого файла python).
3. Их может менять кто угодно. Установка одной программы, потенциально, может переписать переменные, которые используются другой.

Так что:

1. Аргументы командной строки (флаги) использовать для параметров, которые разные для каждого вызова программы. К примеру, если программа вычисляет факториал, а на вход нужно передать число.
2. Конфиги для относительно неизменных параметров (адрес базы данных, размер пула, размер экрана и т.п.). Хотя, адрес, всё же, лучше из какого-нибудь сервис дискавери сервиса получать.
3. Переменные окружения для вещей, которые используются разными программами и не планируют меняться.